# Achartengine XYChart.toScreenPoint always returns NULLPointerException

Tags: android, achartengine

I'm trying to retrieve screen coordinates of series points of a (AchartEngine) TimeChart but method toScreenPoint always returns me a NullPointerException.

Here is the code:

```
TimeChart chart = new TimeChart(dataSet, renderer);
XYSeries serie = dataSet.getSeriesAt(0);

for(int u=0;u<serie.getItemCount();u++)
{
    double dy = serie.getY(u);
    double dx = serie.getX(u);

    double[] pos = chart.toScreenPoint(new double[]{dx,dy}, 0);
}
```

Is there something I should initialiize when instantiating the TimeChart?

Answer (score 0):

Here is a code for a timegraph. You need to edit the fillData with your own code.

```
private void chartView() {

        layout = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.graph);

        // create dataset and renderer
        mDataset = new XYMultipleSeriesDataset();
        mRenderer = new XYMultipleSeriesRenderer();
        mRenderer.setAxisTitleTextSize(16);
        mRenderer.setChartTitleTextSize(20);
        mRenderer.setLabelsTextSize(15);
        mRenderer.setLegendTextSize(15);
        mRenderer.setPointSize(3f);

        XYSeriesRenderer r = new XYSeriesRenderer();
        r.setColor(Color.CYAN);
        r.setPointStyle(PointStyle.DIAMOND);
        r.setFillPoints(true);
        mRenderer.addSeriesRenderer(r);
        mRenderer.setClickEnabled(true);
        mRenderer.setSelectableBuffer(20);
        mRenderer.setPanEnabled(true);

        time_series = new TimeSeries("Weight");

        mDataset.addSeries(time_series);

        fillData();

        mChartView = ChartFactory.getTimeChartView(this, mDataset, mRenderer,
                "H:mm:ss");

        layout.addView(mChartView);
    }

private void fillData() {
    long value = new Date().getTime() - 3 * TimeChart.DAY;
    for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
        time_series.add(new Date(value + i * TimeChart.DAY / 4), i);
    }
}
```

Hope this helps you!

Comment: Thank you for your help but i think i'm missing something.
I already have the mChartView but i cannot find a way to obtain the TimeChart object from it (to use toScreenPoint() which is a method of TimeChart class).

Comment: `public double[] toRealPoint(float screenX, float screenY, int scale)`
`Transforms a screen point to a real coordinates point.
Parameters:
screenX - the screen x axis value
screenY - the screen y axis value
Returns:
the real coordinates point`

Comment: I need the screen coordinates
Example:
onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event){ 
screenX = event.getX(); 
screenY = event.getX(); 
}
 not the real coordinates